# NestJS - Validate missing parameter in POST

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have the following DTO:

```
@Expose()
@IsNotEmpty({ message: 'Please provide value for target language' })
@ApiProperty({
example: 'javascript',
description: `Searches repositories in provided programming language.
These languages are supported 
${process.env.SEARCH_BY_PROGRAMMING_LANGUAGE.toLowerCase()}`,
})
@Transform(({ value }) => value.toLowerCase())
@IsIn(process.env.SEARCH_BY_PROGRAMMING_LANGUAGE.toLowerCase().split(','))
programming_language: string;
```

I have problem with validation. It works as expected, untill I do not send the "programming_language" property.

When I say it works good, as long as the property is present.
If I do not send the property, the app throws 500 due to this line:

```
@Transform(({ value }) => value.toLowerCase())
```

It still tried to get the property, but its not there, and it crashes.
How can I make my DTO to also validate missing property, and not only value?

I would expect to see a message along the lines:
Please provide the "programming_language" property.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple as is.
I have extended the @transform decorator, like this:

```
@Transform(({ value }) => {
    if (value) {
      return value.toLowerCase();
    }
  })
```

If the property is missing, it will not attempy to perform function on the string(toLowerCase), therefore avoding operation on null.